# error when populating list based on class in generic method

Tags: c#, .net, list, class

I have a list defined as below in each of 11 different classes (which handle web-services)

```
private List<edbService> genEdbService;

internal class edbService
{
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDescr { get; set; }
    public string ServiceInterval { get; set; }
    public string ServiceStatus { get; set; }
    public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
    public string SourceApplication { get; set; }
    public string DestinationApplication { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string credentials { get; set; }
    public string orgid { get; set; }
    public string orgunit { get; set; }
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

The list is populated in each class by reading the web-service configuration data from xml files in each class:

```
public DCSSCustomerCreate_V3_0()
{
try
{
    XElement x = XElement.Load(global::EvryCardManagement.Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + "CustomerCreate.xml");
    // Get global settings        
    IEnumerable<XElement> services = from el in x.Descendants("Service")
         select el;
    if (services != null)
    {
        edb_service = new List<edbService>();

        // edb_service= Common.populateEDBService("CustomerCreate.xml");

        foreach (XElement srv in services)
        {
        edbService edbSrv = new edbService();

        edbSrv.ServiceID = srv.Element("ServiceID").Value;
        edbSrv.ServiceName = srv.Element("ServiceName").Value;
        edbSrv.ServiceDescr = srv.Element("ServiceDescr").Value;
        edbSrv.ServiceInterval = srv.Element("ServiceInterval").Value;
        edbSrv.ServiceStatus = srv.Element("ServiceStatus").Value;
        edbSrv.ServiceUrl = srv.Element("ServiceUrl").Value;
        foreach (XElement ServiceHeader in srv.Elements("ServiceHeader"))
        {
        ...
```

now what I want to do is have this code in one place in my Common.cs class so I tried:

```
public static List<edbService> populateEDBService(string xmlDataFile)
{
    try
    {
    XElement x = XElement.Load(global::EvryCardManagement.Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + xmlDataFile);

    // Get global settings
    IEnumerable<XElement> services = from el in x.Descendants("Service")
         select el;
    if (services != null)
    {
      //edb_Service = new List<edbService>();
      foreach (XElement srv in services)
      {
      edbService edbSrv = new edbService();

      edbSrv.ServiceID = srv.Element("ServiceID").Value;
      edbSrv.ServiceName = srv.Element("ServiceName").Value;
      edbSrv.ServiceDescr = srv.Element("ServiceDescr").Value;
      edbSrv.ServiceInterval = srv.Element("ServiceInterval").Value;
      edbSrv.ServiceStatus = srv.Element("ServiceStatus").Value;
      edbSrv.ServiceUrl = srv.Element("ServiceUrl").Value;

      foreach (XElement ServiceHeader in srv.Elements("ServiceHeader"))
        {
        edbSrv.SourceApplication = ServiceHeader.Element("SourceApplication").Value;
        edbSrv.DestinationApplication = ServiceHeader.Element("DestinationApplication").Value;
        edbSrv.Function = ServiceHeader.Element("Function").Value;
        edbSrv.Version = ServiceHeader.Element("Version").Value;

        foreach (XElement ClientContext in ServiceHeader.Elements("ClientContext"))
          {
          edbSrv.userid = ClientContext.Element("userid").Value;
          edbSrv.credentials = ClientContext.Element("credentials").Value;
          edbSrv.orgid = ClientContext.Element("orgid").Value;
          edbSrv.orgunit = ClientContext.Element("orgunit").Value;
          edbSrv.customerid = ClientContext.Element("customerid").Value;
          edbSrv.channel = ClientContext.Element("channel").Value;
          edbSrv.ip = ClientContext.Element("ip").Value;
          }
        }

     // populateEDBService.Add(edbSrv);
     }
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    /* Write to log */
    Common.logBuilder("CustomerCreate : Form --> CustomerCreate <--", "Exception", Common.ActiveMQ,
       ex.Message, "Exception");
    /* Send email to support */
    emailer.exceptionEmail(ex);
    }
return;
}
```

Now I get a compile error on the `return;` saying that `An object of a type convertible to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EvryCardManagement.Common.edbService>' is required`

and in the class that should call this method, I want to do something like:

```
edb_service = Common.populateEDBService("CustomerUpdate.xml");
```

but I get an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EvryCardManagement.Common.edbService>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EvryCardManagement.CustomerUpdate.edbService>'`

So firstly how should I return the list from my generic method and how should I call it to return the list populated with the configuration data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have your class edbService defined in two namespaces,

EvryCardManagement.Common and
EvryCardManagement.CustomerUpdate

I would suggest defining it in only EvryCardManagement.Common and have everything reference it from there.

Comment: Thanks (that works!), but how should I write it so that the method returns a populated list?

Comment: You just need to add a declaration of a local variable of type List<edbService>.  Then add edbService objects to this list in your loop, then return the list at the end of the function.

Comment: I tried `edb_service = Common.populateSoapBody<edbService>("CardUpdate.xml");` to call the procedure but I get an error

Comment: What is populateSoapBody?  What is the error?  Worthe closing this thread and starting a new one?